# Reset Number and Date fields based on a ComboBox selection is not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, power-platform

I have this screen which contain 9 fields (4 number fields + 4 date fields) + a combo-box contain (1, 2,3,4):-

[image]

now i want to reset the fields based on the Combobox selection, so if the user select NumberOfInstallment = 1, to clear the 6 fields (for Second, Third and Forth) and so on.

so inside the screen on visible , i define this to capture the values of those fields and store them inside variables:-

```
Set(varSIP,varSecondApp.'Second Installment Percentage');
Set(varTIP,varSecondApp.'Third Installment Percentage');
Set(varFIP,varSecondApp.'Fourth Installment Percentage');
Set(varSID,varSecondApp.'Second Installment Date');
Set(varTID,varSecondApp.'Third Installment Date');
Set(varFID,varSecondApp.'Fourth Installment Date');
```

then inside the Combobox OnSelect , i set this:-

```
Switch(Value(NumberOfInstallments.Selected.Value),
1
,
Set(varSIP,Blank());
Set(varTIP,Blank());
Set(varFIP,Blank());
Set(varSID,Blank());
Set(varTID,Blank());
Set(varFID,Blank());
Notify("1");
,
2
,
Set(varTIP,Blank());
Set(varFIP,Blank());
Set(varTID,Blank());
Set(varFID,Blank());
Notify("2");
,
3
,
Set(varFIP,Blank());
Set(varFID,Blank());
Notify("3");

);
```

and for each of the field i set their default value as follow:-

```
If (IsBlank(varFID),ThisItem.'Fourth Installment Date',varFID)
```

currently when i change the combobox selection, i will get a notify message, but the fields will not be cleared ,, any advice?

Thansk

Comment: Try `Reset(txtControlName)` after `Set()` for respective number controls. Let me know if it works.